# Saving Rmd script without preview

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

Whenever I tries to save the working .Rmd script, Rstudio automatically knits the file and this causes my Rstudio to stop for a while ( not responding thing).

How can I save my Rmd file without knitting it ?

Comment: More information, please.

Comment: `ctrl-s` works for me